# python summing over 2d array to get a 1d array

Tags: python, numpy, numerical-integration

Say I have an 2d array (x,y) and the values of the function z=F(x,y)

```
   x = y = array([ 1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.])

   z= array([[  1.,   2.,   3.,   4.,   5.],
       [  2.,   4.,   6.,   8.,  10.],
       [  3.,   6.,   9.,  12.,  15.],
       [  4.,   8.,  12.,  16.,  20.],
       [  5.,  10.,  15.,  20.,  25.]])
```

Now what i want to find is the integration $P(w)=\int F(x,y) \delta(x-y=w) dx dy $
for this I construct w matrix by doing w = x-y
which gives me something like

```
   w= array([[ 0.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  4.],
       [-1.,  0.,  1.,  2.,  3.],
       [-2., -1.,  0.,  1.,  2.],
       [-3., -2., -1.,  0.,  1.],
       [-4., -3., -2., -1.,  0.]])
```

Now i must add up all values of z corresponding to w ,say w = 3 I should get 4+10=14.

*Question is what is the best way to do the last part?*

**P.S**. This is an example, the arrays are in general not equal and doesnt have the symmetry as in this example.
Iterating  would be a bad option, I guess, as these arrays are quite large.

Comment: you must post this question on http://math.stackexchange.com !

Comment: @Kasra: No, that would be completely off topic.

Comment: I'm not sure the integral you're trying to compute makes much sense or that the way you're trying to compute it is going to work. It looks to me like you'll run into a lot of problems with floating-point rounding error and your grid not capturing the points where `w` takes the value you want.

Comment: Can you suggest a better way? This is only for plotting purposes, and will suffice my requirements partially, but anything better is worth trying. I have numerical values of F(x,y) only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a good place to use [`np.unique`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) and numpy's new (v1.8.2) [`np.add.at`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.at.html) function:

```
uvals, uidx = np.unique(w, return_inverse=True)

output = np.zeros_like(uvals)
np.add.at(output, uidx, z.ravel())

print uvals
# [-4. -3. -2. -1.  0.  1.  2.  3.  4.]
print output
# [  5.  14.  26.  40.  55.  40.  26.  14.   5.]
```

Comment: Exactly what I wanted!This does the job perfectly, and speeds up the whole thing by almost 1000 times the way i was doing using dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

```
z[w == 3].sum()
```

`w == 3` builds a boolean array representing which locations of `w` have a 3. `z[w == 3]` gives an array of the elements of `z` corresponding to those locations, and `sum()` adds them up. You'll learn a lot of this kind of stuff in the [NumPy tutorial](https://web.archive.org/web/20150802020005/http://wiki.scipy.org/Tentative_NumPy_Tutorial), and you'll learn even more in the [NumPy reference](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/).

Comment: good idea, but can you somehow get all possible "different" values of w in the beginning ? I was thinking with dict, how can we add up?

Comment: @Ars3nous: What do you mean? You can plug in whatever variable or other expression you want in place of `3`, if you want to use a different value there.